# GCP pricing API does not have data for compute instances like N2, M2, C1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Problem: Currently we are using the price calculator API from Google to calculate the estimated cost for GCP compute instances. But as observed it does not have the data for N2, M2, C1, etc. instances. As suggested from google we tried the billing catalog API and found that still, data was missing for the N2, M2 & c1 instances. And Catalog API is very dense and is not very developer-friendly

Can we get any official working API from google to calculate the pricing for these compute instances?

Existing API which does not have the N2, M2 & C1 instances data:
https://cloudpricingcalculator.appspot.com/static/data/pricelist.json

New API from google for catalog billing using the SKU id:

https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key=

here **6F81-5844-456A** is the SKU id for compute engines

Comment: You understand that Stack overflow is not google support right?  
What exactly is it that you think we can help you with?

Comment: @DaImTo, of course, this is not google support but I believe this is a platform to share technical problems and answers with the community.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the list of available configurations [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types).
N2 data is available through the API.
C1 type is not available, API or otherwise.
To obtain pricing of M2, you have to [request a quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#larger_ultramem):

> If the machine types above don't match your workloads, you can choose from the following list of machine types that have larger amounts of memory per vCPU. To use these machine types, you must request quota using one of the following options:
>
> Request access to evaluation quota so that you can test the performance of these machine types. Any VMs you create with these machine types count against the evaluation quota and are billed using the evaluative prices listed below. Evaluation quota persists only for a limited amount of time on your project.
>
> Purchase a 1 year or 3 year commitment for sustained usage. Commitments are not billed incrementally. Commitments bill you a monthly fee for the duration of your commitment term even if you do not use any of the committed resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you give me a reference where I can see the data for N2 instances from the https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key= API. This would be of great help

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can call this API and it will return a 6MB file full of specs. Information on this exact API can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest

Comment: Yes I am using the same API from this reference i.e. https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/6F81-5844-456A/skus?key=
So this does not have data for N2 instances

Comment: I ran grep "N2 Instance" on this file and found 54 results. Is that not the data you are looking for?

Comment: Nope that is not the data for compute instances VM..N2 data is only available for RAM and CPU, not the complete instance data like how we have for N!. For example:

`"category": {
        "serviceDisplayName": "Compute Engine",
        "resourceFamily": "Compute",
        "resourceGroup": "N1Standard",
        "usageType": "OnDemand"
      },`

Comment: @Imran - Is there a reason you cannot use the component pricing model instead of instance pricing model? Google uses both.